# Opening docx and pdf documents in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, pdf, docx

Faced a number of problems opening documents in a mobile application. We have 2 types of PDF and DOCX documents available.
There are no packages to open Docx for react native.
In order to open a pdf, you need to have the base64 of that document. The back-end does not give back, and in order for the mobile application to create it itself, you need to fasten a heavy package.

Two types of documents can be opened in webview, but only viewing without saving will be available there, and then, this will only work on ios, android immediately starts downloading documents without viewing.
**You can use the google.docs service to view documents, but you won't be able to open the document without cookies.** Our back-end doesn't let the google.docs robot (for obvious reasons) download the document and display it to us.

Comment: `In order to open a pdf, you need to have the base64 of that document.` ? Why? I see no reason. Why doesnt your app let the user choose a reader for those documents? They are files on your device i think.

Comment: `Two types of documents can be opened in webview, ` Yes. At least .html and .txt. But not .doc and .pdf.

Comment: Convert all your documents in PDFs and use this package for preview - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf